# The proper way of creating a wrapper component for the Angular Material mat-list-option component

Tags: angular-2+

For an angular project I need a customized version of the `mat-list-option` component.
I've found a solution by creating my own component and using `mat-list-option` inside of it.
Unfortunately the parent `mat-selection-list` didn't recognise the custom component as list options and therefore it didn't work with the reactive form.

I've added this workaround:

```
@ViewChild('listOption')
listOption!: MatListOption;

@Input()
selectionList?: MatSelectionList;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  if (this.selectionList) {
    this.selectionList.options.reset([...this.selectionList.options.toArray(), this.listOption]);
  }
}
```

```
<mat-selection-list #selectionList formControlName="participants">
  <app-participant-list-item
    [selectionList]="selectionList"
    *ngFor="let participant of participants"
    [participant]="participant"
  ></app-participant-list-item>
</mat-selection-list>
```

By passing the reference of the MatSelectionList to the component, it's possible to add the options to the list manually.

I would love to hear, if this is the proper way to do it with Angular? If not, can you also give me a hint in which direction I can head to?